# Error handling not working for slide ID

Tags: vba, error-handling, runtime-error, powerpoint

having trouble dealing with an exception in my code. I have written the code below to transfer the contents of a powerpoint table into an array, but it keeps throwing an exception saying

> Slides (unknown member): Invalid request. Invalid Slide ID.

I put in the error handle to try and skip this, as it does not matter to me if the entry is left blank in the case of errors. However, I cannot get it to pass this error! (I cannot use resume next). Any help would be great.

```
'loop through table and store values to a temporary array in order to sort it
'NOTE that the Table starts at (1,1) and the  storage array starts at (0,0) (see "j")
For j = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count

    'First check that the string being stored is a hyperlink and not an empty cell
    If Not (oTbl.Cell(j, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.SubAddress) = "" Then

        'create a temp variable to operate on the hyperlink address in each row in the table
        subAd = oTbl.Cell(j, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.SubAddress

        'Find the CURRENT slideIndex and store in column 1 (for sorting)
        'write error condition for if the slideID points to a slide that has been deleted
On Error GoTo errCatch
        pLinkNumber = Left(subAd, InStr(subAd, ",") - 1)
        aStorage(j - 1, 1) = ActivePresentation.slideS.FindBySlideID(CLng(pLinkNumber)).SlideIndex

        'store the CURRENT hyperlink address as column 0 (after defining colum 1 for error handling reasons)
        aStorage(j - 1, 0) = subAd

    Else
errCatch:
    End If
Next j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error path is intertwined with your "happy path".

Good error handling should be in its own execution path.

I'd rename that `errCatch` label to e.g. `Skip`, and then at the bottom of the procedure, add this:

```
    Exit Sub
 ErrCatch:
     Err.Clear
     Resume Skip
```

Now the "happy path" ends at `Exit Sub`, and the "error path" jumps to this little subroutine which clears the error and resumes to the `Skip` label. That "resume" part is what tells the VBA runtime "hey, we're no longer in an error state" - currently your code enters error state, and then nothing tells VBA you're done handling that error, so `errCatch` gets jumped to, and then the "happy path" is understood by VBA as being the error-handling subroutine: it's expecting you to handle the error and eventually `Resume` to the "happy path", but what's happening is that the error is essentially unhandled, and the error state is persisting into the next loop iteration.

That said the `On Error GoTo` statement should probably be pulled out of the loop scope, assuming `oTbl.Rows.Count` has no reason to fail (or does it?). It running on every iteration is redundant.

---

> I cannot use *resume next*

Why not? In its own limited scope, it's a fine tool to have!

```
Private Function GetSlideByID(ByVal id As Long) As Slide
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetSlideByID = ActivePresentation.slideS.FindBySlideID(id)
End Function
```

Now you can do this:

```
Dim thisSlide As Slide
Set thisSlide = GetSlideByID(CLng(pLinkNumber))
If Not thisSlide Is Nothing Then
    aStorage(j - 1, 1) = thisSlide.SlideIndex
    aStorage(j - 1, 0) = subAd
End If
```

And there's no need for an `On Error` statement *or* line labels anymore!

Comment: Wow, what a great answer! Thank you for your help, that worked.

Comment: @Stuart feel free to mark this answer as "accepted", by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the voting buttons, near the top of the post!

Comment: Thanks again for that. It really streamlines the code. I implemented the function that you suggested. Still learning VBA and appreciate your help!

Comment: @Stuart allow me to shamelessly plug my VBIDE add-in project then - see the links in my profile =)